# Find total term count in Solr index

Tags: solr, lucene

I need to figure out how many unique terms are in our Solr (Lucene) index.  And by unique terms, I dont mean by document.  I mean total unique terms from all documents in the index.  The Solr admin console shows how many documents, but not total terms.

I found a tool called Luke (Lucene Index Toolbox) that will give you that info, but its a UI tool, and my Sorl index is on a Ubuntu server so I cant run it.

Any Ideas?

Comment: do you need to do this programmatically? what do you intend to do with that information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [LukeRequestHandler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/LukeRequestHandler). You should see the tag "numTerms" in the xml returned.

Comment: Thanks.  I ended up running Luke over X11 (like a super slow terminal service) and got the info I needed before I saw your post.  Glad Solr put luke into its admin features.