# Find total number of terms indexed in a particular document solr

Tags: solr

I have read extensively about solr and it gives me the ability to find termfreq i.e. the number of times the required text is available in the document. But I need to know the total number of terms that have been indexed in a particular document. The query I am trying is

/solr/live/select?qt=albumsearch&q=pak%20pak&fl=*%2Cscore&wt=json&indent=true&defType=edismax&q.alt=as&qf=a%5E10+l%5E10&bf=12234&boost=termfreq(song,.*)

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find total term count in Solr index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306240/find-total-term-count-in-solr-index)

Answer (score 0):

You can use either [the Luke Request Handler](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/LukeRequestHandler) with a `docId` parameter, or [use the Stats Component](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Stats+Component) with a query / `fq` that results the document you're interested in.

Comment: I actually need to store the value of total terms and then use it later in the same query, can I do that? If possible could u give an example

Comment: No, not that I know of. You really should ask the specific question about the issue you're having. A quick fix would be to index the number of terms (which should be very close to the number achived by splitting by whitespace or special characters) in a field attached to the document, then use that field as the boost.